# C++ Reading from a text file and calculating total for each line:

Tags: c++, io, computer-science, ifstream

I have to write a program in C++ that will read from a text file and calculate total for each lines. The text file looks like this

```
2
14.4 56.9 54 65.7 86.9
98.6 84.9 34.7 85.5 15.4
24.4 57.9 54.9 70.7 63.5

34.4 16.9 41.9 54.7 84.98
97.6 84.9 14.7 85.5 16.4
23.4 76.9 54.9 74.7 64.5
```

The first line has the number of weeks. The lines that follow have five doubles each (3 line per each week). ANd it will repeat the number of weeks given in the first line. So far I have this code to calculate the total for each week. SOmehow it gives me 0 as the total before each week

```
string s; 
 double sum[4]; 

 for(int j = 0; j < weeks; j++)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i <= 3 && getline(in, s); i++)
         {
            istringstream sin(s);
            sum[i] = 0;
            while (sin>>sales)
            {
               sum[i] = sum[i] + sales;
            }
            cout << sum[i] << endl;
         } 
    }
```

And here's the outcome :

```
0
277.9
319.1
271.4
0
232.88
299.1
294.4
```

Can somebody tell me why am i getting that 0?  Also how should I store the numbers as total for each line. The number of lines would vary based on number weeks. SOmebody help please!

Comment: you can use the following module: http://code.google.com/p/inih/

Comment: You could always try debugging it.  Why not display 's' at the top of the sum loop?  It's easy to get simple things like loop conditions wrong, so intermediate locals and copious display calls are your friend, (if not an actual debugger:)

Comment: The main problem is blank lines. Are you sure you want to use `getline`? Stream input would be a lot simpler for this problem, but maybe your goal is to learn to use `getline`...

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. I'm sure the teacher gave you a book to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are summing the numbers for the blank lines between each group. Since there are no number on these lines, the sum of course remains at zero. I also assume that you are not reading in the whole first line to get the number of weeks, so there is a leading zero there too. To solve the problem, simply read an extra line before starting each week, like this:

```
string s; 
double sum[4]; 

for(int j = 0; j < weeks; j++)
{
    getline(in, s);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 && getline(in, s); i++)
    {
        istringstream sin(s);
        sum[i] = 0;
        while (sin>>sales)
        {
           sum[i] = sum[i] + sales;
        }
        cout << sum[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
```

Output is:

```
277.9
319.1
271.4

232.88
299.1
294.4
```

Comment: That worked for getting rid of the 0. I have to out the total and average of each line in a separate text file. How should i store the totals? Like inside the loop, or outside? There are 6 totals for this particular situation, but it will deffer based on the number of weeks (weeks * 3). ANy leads on that would be appreciated. And thanks for the help above!

Comment: Each line has exactly 5 parts right? (The problem states this) When you finish each line, output the sum (which you already have) and the average (sum / 5) right after the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check that it is not an empty line like this:

```
 if (!s.empty())
 {
     cout << sum[i] << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the number of weeks was read using operator >>. After that the next getline call read an empty string. It would explaing the first zero. Also I see that there is an empty line between two triads of lines. So it seems you again read an empty line.
Apart from this I do not understand why you are using the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3 && getline(in, s); i++)
```

if there are only three lines for a week.

So you need check whether an empty line was read.